# Laravel Meilisearch using non-case sensitive filters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I am trying to search and filter using **Meilisearch** and **Laravel Scout**.

### Database Table Sample:

`

| id | name | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Panadol | 123 |
| 2 | Cometrex | 456 |
| 3 | Panadol | 789 |

`

### Data From Frontend:

- `query = pana` (It is a string for search and it will search for all columns)
- `filters[['column' => 'code', 'value' => '23']` (It is not mandatory to send filters but user may use filters aligned with search)

### Expected result:

It should return product with ID 1 because it matches BOTH search and filter.

### What I have tried:

I have integrated Meilisearch and indexed all my model data and used the search method.

`public function search(Request $request) { return tap(Product::search($request->q)->paginate(10), function ($q) { return $q->load('category'); }); }`

How can I add the filter  to the search function? I have tried to use `where` but it is case-sensitive means that user should type the entire keyword for filtering.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it returns the data"... can you post the result to the tap function?

Comment: Can you please check now

Answer (score 0):

```
$filters = $this->filters();
$results = Product::search(
    $query,
    function (Indexes $meiliSearch, string $query, array $options) use ($filters) 
    {
        $options['filter'] = $filters;
        return $meiliSearch->search($query, $options);
    }
);

protected function filters()
 {
  if (request('name')) 
  {
     $options ? $options .= ' AND name =' . request('name') : $options .= 'name 
     =' . request('name');
  }
  return $options;
}
```

Comment: may be this will help you

Comment: Thank you Mansour. Your answer is very good but the problem it returns the exact match for the filter not using LIKE